# gridview footer

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view which contains Hours as one of the columns.. now, i need to have a total hours in the footer (sum of hours for all rows).. how do we add that? pls help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MSDN tutorials:

1. [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Displaying Summary Data in the Footer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx)
2. [Displaying Summary Information in the GridView's Footer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310552.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' 検索を行う
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection( _
            SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter( _
            "SELECT count(*), sum(age) FROM person", cn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        ' 人数と年齢の合計を取得する
        Dim n As Integer = CType(dt.Rows(0)(0), Integer)    ' 人数
        Dim sum As Integer = CType(dt.Rows(0)(1), Integer)  ' 年齢の合計
        ' フッターに設定する
        GridView1.Columns(0).FooterText = String.Format("{0}人", n)
        GridView1.Columns(1).FooterText = String.Format("合計{0}", sum)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

As each row is rendered (i.e. when the RowDataBound event it called) You need to keep a running total of the hours for each row, the following code should do it. (Modified version of the example from the MSDN Site)

Once you get to the RowDataBound event for the footer, you display the total number of hours.

```
' This will keep the running total for the number of hours, and should be placed at the top of your page class

Dim Hours as Integer 


Sub detailsGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Hours  += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Hours"))

    ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Totals Hours:"
        e.Row.Cells(1).Text = Hours.ToString("c")           
        e.Row.Cells(1).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        e.Row.Cells(2).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        e.Row.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

take grid-view elements to a data-table ,calculate total of each column programmatically ,
Make footer templates for grid-view , insert labels ,Find labels on the event which you want and bind data.